# Filter by Key in a Dictionary within a List of objects?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have created `List<YouTubeChannelInfo>` which contains many List of YouTube Channels.

`YouTubeChannelInfo` has a Dictionary attribute called 'Playlists' which contains Playlist Title as the key and the ID as the value. Thus there could be many playlists for a given channel.

```
public class YouTubeChannelInfo
{

    public string Name { get; set; } // Channel Name
    public Dictionary<string, string> Playlists { get; set; } // Key - Playlist Title, Value - Playlist ID
}
```

I have `string[] playlists` which contains an array of playlist titles and need to filter only the YouTube Channels based on those playlist titles.

```
List<YouTubeChannelInfo> youTubeChannelsInfo = GetChannels();
string[] playlists = GetPlaylists();
youTubeChannelsInfo = FilterByPlaylists(youTubeChannelsInfo, playlists); // Anyway to do this ?
```

It will be better if I can filter that by using Linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as using [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2), and [`ContainsKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
List<YouTubeChannelInfo> youTubeChannelsInfo = GetChannels();
string[] playlists = GetPlaylists();
var filtered = youTubeChannelsInfo.Where(x => playLists.Any(y => x.Playlists.ContainsKey(y))).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks :) This works. Nice that you have come up with a linq expression